# Interval of convergence of a Laplace-Stieltjes transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a two-sided Laplace-Stieltjes transform,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-xt}d\mu(t)
$$
that converges absolutely in $(a,b)$.

If the measure $\mu$ is finite,then 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}d\mu(t)=\mu(\mathbb{R})<\infty
$$
can I conclude that $(a,b)$ MUST contain the origin?

In general, how changes the interval of convergence of a two-sided Laplace-Stieltjes transform with respect to $\mu$?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if $\mu$ is not a positive measure, its total variation measure $|\mu|$ is, and  "the integral converges 
absolutely" means $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-xt}\ d|\mu|(t) < \infty$.
Now $\int_{A} e^{-xt}\ d|\mu|(t)$ is a convex function of $x$ for every measurable $A \subseteq \mathbb R$, so the set where this is finite is a convex set, i.e. an interval.  If $\mu$ is a finite measure, that says $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-xt}\ d|\mu|(t) < \infty$ for $x=0$, so $0$ is in the interval.

Note, however, that the interval doesn't have to be open.  For example,
take the measure with density $1/x^2$ for $x > 1$, $0$ elsewhere: this has interval $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Do you know if is it possible to prove analyticity of the laplace-stieltjes transform for a $\mu$ non-finite? Eventually, do you have some references?

Comment: If $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-xt}\ d|\mu|(t)$ converges for $x \in (a,b)$, then $\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-zt}\ d\mu(t)$ should be analytic in $a < \text{Re}(z) < b$, as this will be the limit of $\int_{-R}^R e^{-zt}\ d\mu(t)$ as $R \to \infty$, and convergence will be uniform on $c \le \text{Re}(z) \le d$ if $a < c < d < b$.

Answer (score 0):

In case $\mu$ is finite positive, let us consider its normalization $\mu'(\cdot):=\mu(\cdot)/\mu(\Bbb R)$ which is clearly a probability measure on reals. As a result,
$$
  f_\mu(x):=\int_\Bbb R\mathrm e^{-xt}\mu(\mathrm dt) = \mu(\Bbb R)\int_\Bbb R\mathrm e^{-xt}\mu'(\mathrm dt) = \mu(\Bbb R)f_{\mu'}(x)  = \mu(\Bbb R)m_{\mu'}(-x).
$$
where $m_{\mu'}$ is a [moment-generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) (MGF) of the distribution $\mu'$. Clearly, the LHS is finite iff the RHS is, so that your question for positive finite $\mu$ is equivalent to studying the properties of MGF and in particular of [heavy-tailed distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution). Note, the clearly $m_{\mu'}(0) = 1$ regardless of $\mu'$, but it does not have to exist anywhere else, e.g. if $\mu'$ is [Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).

Comment: Thus, $\mu$ is positive and finite iff $(a,b)$ contain the origin?

Comment: @alexou No, $\mu$ is finite iff the integral converges for the origin (trivial). However, even if $\mu$ is finite and positive, the integral may not converge anywhere else.